# Single CTE with multiple SELECTs, CTE created twice in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, common-table-expression

Requirement is to join(pair) two tables on some fields and then show pair wise results in order. Pairing is being done in CTE. A pair is assigned a GUID which is then used to show each pair in order.
It works as expected for Oracle (11.2) but for SQL Server (2017), it seems the CTE is created twice because each row has its own GUID.

How can i solve it using CTE? Why SQL Server is behaving like this?

**SQL Server** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/21c167/1

**Oracle** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c49dbb/2 *(DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM has been used instead of SYS_GUID() because SYS_GUID() was returning same value for all rows on sqlfiddle.com while working fine on my dev machine)*

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLE (CODE NUMERIC(3,0), [TYPE] VARCHAR(50), DRIVER_CATEGORY VARCHAR(2));
CREATE TABLE DRIVER (CODE NUMERIC(9,0), NAME VARCHAR(200), CATEGORY VARCHAR(2));
 
INSERT INTO VEHICLE VALUES (1, 'LIMOUSINE', 'A');
INSERT INTO VEHICLE VALUES (2, 'TRUCK', 'B');
INSERT INTO VEHICLE VALUES (3, 'SUV', 'C');
INSERT INTO VEHICLE VALUES (4, 'SEDAN', 'C');
INSERT INTO VEHICLE VALUES (5, 'SPORTS CAR', 'D');
  
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES (1, 'James', 'A');
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES (2, 'Robert', 'B');
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES (3, 'John', 'C');
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES (4, 'Jennifer', 'C');
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES (5, 'Patricia', 'D');
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES (6, 'Susan', 'A');     
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES (7, 'Lisa', 'B');     

  ;WITH MATCHPAIRS AS 
  ( 
      SELECT V.CODE VEHICLE_CODE, D.CODE DRIVER_CODE, V.TYPE TYPE, V.DRIVER_CATEGORY, D.NAME, D.CATEGORY, NewID() PAIRID
      FROM VEHICLE V INNER JOIN DRIVER D ON V.DRIVER_CATEGORY = D.CATEGORY
  )
    SELECT p.VEHICLE_CODE, p.DRIVER_CODE, P.PAIRID, V.TYPE TYPE_NAME, 0 RECORD_ORDER  
    FROM VEHICLE V INNER JOIN MATCHPAIRS P ON V.CODE = P.VEHICLE_CODE 
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT p.VEHICLE_CODE, p.DRIVER_CODE, P.PAIRID, D.NAME TYPE_NAME, 1 RECORD_ORDER  
    FROM DRIVER D INNER JOIN MATCHPAIRS P ON D.CODE = P.DRIVER_CODE
    ORDER BY PAIRID, RECORD_ORDER
```

Comment: I see no code above. A question here is supposed to be self-contained. (And a fiddle _too_ is great.)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't load for me, so i have no idea why it isn't working (as you expect). If you have code that isn't working as you expect, include it in the question. Fiddles should *compliment* the question, but they should not be required for us to help you.

Comment: Instead of `NEWID()`, you could use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V.CODE, D.CODE) AS PAIRID` to assign a deterministic surrogate key value.

Comment: CTEs are not cached, they are recalculated for every reference. `NEWID` does weird stuff sometimes, so best to use a temp table. `CROSS APPLY` or `CROSS JOIN` will also not work sometimes. Alterntaively use a different uniquifier as mentioned.

Comment: @Larnu code added

Comment: Common Table Expressions are, as their name suggests, *expressions* and as such the expression is derived *every time* you reference it. If you had `SELECT NEWID() UNION ALL SELECT NEWID()` you would expect 2 different values of `NEWID()`. The same is true here; 2 instances of `NEWID()` won't generate the same value.

Comment: @DanGuzman Effective suggestion with min change, will accept your answer

Comment: @bjan, I was composing an answer when Charlieface posted one incorporating my suggestion plus other improvements. Feel free to accept it as I don't have anything to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CTEs are not cached, they are recalculated for every reference.

In any case, `NEWID` does weird stuff sometimes, when not used on the outermost `SELECT`, so best to use a temp table. `CROSS APPLY` or `CROSS JOIN` will also not work sometimes with `NEWID`.

Alternatively, use a different uniquifier instead. For example

```sql
;WITH MATCHPAIRS AS (
    SELECT
      V.CODE VEHICLE_CODE,
      D.CODE DRIVER_CODE,
      V.TYPE TYPE,
      V.DRIVER_CATEGORY,
      D.NAME,
      D.CATEGORY,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v.CODE, D.CODE) PAIRID
    FROM VEHICLE V
    INNER JOIN DRIVER D ON V.DRIVER_CATEGORY = D.CATEGORY
)
SELECT
  p.VEHICLE_CODE,
  p.DRIVER_CODE,
  P.PAIRID,
  V1.TYPE_NAME,
  v1.RECORD_ORDER  
FROM MATCHPAIRS P
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
  (p.TYPE, 0),
  (p.NAME, 1)
) V1(TYPE_NAME, RECORD_ORDER)
ORDER BY
  PAIRID,
  RECORD_ORDER;
```

Note the use of `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to unpivot, which saves reading the CTE twice.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/21c167/24)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to use a temp table instead of a CTE. If needed, you can wrap the code inside a stored procedure.

Comment: Temp table is under consideration but would prefer to know Why SQL Server is behaving like this.

Comment: @bjan If you look at the execution plan, you will see that this is the way SQL Server uses CTE's. There is no quarantee that they are only executed once.